# How to know if it was clicked on a graphics object

Tags: java, graphics, awt, mouselistener

I have encountered a problem. I have a mouse event.

```
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){


  }
```

And it works fine. But I have shapes.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setSize(50, 50);
r.setLocation(200, 200)
g2d.draw(r);
```

And when the mouse event is triggered I need something check if it was clicked on my rectangle. Not just anywhere on the screen.

```
if (e.ClickedOnRectangle) {
//Do stuff
}
```

Something like that. Any solutions?

**How do check if my mouse was clicked on a AWT (graphics) object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  If the `Shape`s are contained within the container that the mouse events are occurring then it should be a simple case of using the `Shape#contains` method

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if (rect.contains(e.getPoint()) {
        // Was clicked...
    }
}
```

Take a closer look at the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) JavaDocs for more details

Comment: Thanks! Hope others find this helpful too!